# Android Remove Method in Listadapter

Tags: java, android

How can I create remove method in list Adapter to remove row of list view
and how to use this method in my `Activity` ?

```
public void remove(List<contac> contac) {
    list.remove(contac);        
}
```

In my `Activity` :

```
adapter.remove(list.get(i));
```

but it didn't worked, if I use this

```
list.remove(i);
```

worked but after refreshing not changed my list view. 
then use update method:

```
public void updateList(List<contac> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Again it didn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Pls share the code you tried!!!

Comment: in list adapter

     public void remove(List<contac> contac) {
  list.remove(contac);  
  
 }
 in activity

    adapter.remove(list.get(i));

Comment: You should update your post with the codes!!

Comment: is there a `List` inside a `List` ? I think your code is wrong. It must be `public void remove(contac contac) {list.remove(contac);}` doesn't?

Comment: tnx.worked but my base problem is  after refreshing not changed my list view

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25197988?noredirect=1)